# How do I create a new file with NppExec in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, nppexec

In Notepad++, I would like to create a new file and then put the contents of another file in that new file.

This is possible by creating a macro, but the problem is, I have to copy-paste the contents, losing whatever was on the clipboard before, and I don't want that.

So I looked at NppExec. With NppExec, I can put the contents of another file in the currently open file, but I can't seem to find any function to create a new file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is built into NppExec yet, but you can sort of get around it by using npp_open with a file name that does not exist.